# 'Make' command not found

Tags: apt, make

I am having a problem that when I try to use `make` command.

I cannot run the Make command.

Message: `bash: make: command not found`

When I used

```
sudo apt-get remove make
sudo apt-get install make
```

or with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall make
```

it shows

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package make is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'make' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: On using sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential                       it shows :=Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package build-essential

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 iso file was used

Comment: It sounds like the repository may be missing from your software sources - have a look at the information on how to [Add additional software repositories](https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-sources.html) and make sure that at least `xenial main` is selected.

Comment: Have you run update command before installing?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Do an reinstalation of the `build-essential` package:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall build-essential
```

This should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

The program `make` isn't really called that on the package, the package you are looking for is `automake`

Comment: How did you arrive at that conclusion? `dpkg -S $(which make)` says it's in the package `make` on my system

Comment: simply by installing `automake` by accident and then having a package that needed to be compiled with make and it worked, so i went back, removed `automake` downloaded a different package, and it said the same error as op, reinstalled `automake` and it works again